# Creating a profile which can be used everywhere in the app

Tags: ios, swift

I created an `UIViewController` which has two `UITexFields` and an `UIImageView` inside of it.
What I want it to be is a profile page, which provides information usable everywhere in the app.

What I tried to do is the following:

I created a `Class` with this code (*based on [Apple's tutorial on creating apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1)*):

```
import UIKit

Class ProfilClass: NSObject, NSCoding {

    //MARK: Properties

    var bild: UIImage?
    var vorname: String
    var geburt: String

    //MARK: Archiving Paths
    static let DocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
    static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("profil")

    //MARK: Types
    struct propKey {
        static let bildKey = "bild"
        static let vornameKey = "vorname"
        static let geburtKey = "geburt"
    }

    //MARK: Initialization
    init?(bild: UIImage?, vorname: String, geburt: String){
        self.bild = bild
        self.vorname = vorname
        self.geburt = geburt
        super.init()        
        if vorname.isEmpty || geburt.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(bild, forKey: propKey.bildKey)
        aCoder.encodeObject(vorname, forKey: propKey.vornameKey)
        aCoder.encodeObject(geburt, forKey: propKey.geburtKey)
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        let bild = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(propKey.bildKey) as? UIImage
        let vorname = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(propKey.vornameKey) as! String
        let geburt = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(propKey.geburtKey) as! String
        self.init(bild: bild, vorname: vorname, geburt: geburt)
    }   
}
```

I try to use this Class inside of my `UIViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   [...]
    if let profil = profil{
        vornameLabel.text = profil.vorname
        vornameField.text = profil.vorname
        profilePic.image = profil.bild
        geburtstagsLabel.text = profil.geburt
        geburtstagField.text = profil.geburt
    }

}
```

And when a save button is tapped:

```
@IBAction func butTap(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let vorname = vornameField.text
        let geburt = geburtstagField.text
        let bild = profilePic.image
        profil = ProfilClass(bild: bild, vorname: vorname!, geburt: geburt!)
}
```

But after I close the `UIViewController` by going back to another one and reopen it, all the information is lost.
I don't know how to get the information again (I assume it is saved somewhere).

*Can anyone help me?*

Comment: You should use Singleton pattern here.

Comment: Singletons have nothing to do with this. They just need to continue onto the next chapter in the tutorial they are following – see my answer below.

Comment: You have created a directory **profil** inside document directory and set complete path to **ArchiveURL**, but you never used that. You should write your data on **ArchiveURL** (path of document directory) and than you have to read it whenever you want to use your data.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake comes right at the end:

> I assume it is saved somewhere

It is not, unless you ask for it to be saved. You need to use `NSUserDefaults` or `NSKeyedArchiver` to write your object. You've written all the code required to make that work, now you just need to do the reading and writing.

For example, to write your saved data you'll need something like this:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(profil, forKey: "SavedUserProfile")
```

I can't comment on *reading* because you have limited the code you posted:

```
[...]
if let profil = profil{
```

That is where your reading code should happen. I'm guessing(!) you're doing something like this:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let profil = defaults.objectForKey("SavedUserProfile") as? ProfilClass
```

**As you're following a specific Apple tutorial**: You might find it easier just to continue following there rather than trying to use a different solution. Specifically, you need to continue onto the heading "Save and Load the Meal List", which is where the actual saving and loading happens. Apple writes the data to disk rather than user defaults, so you should follow along.

To be clear: the code you've written only enables your object to be saved and loaded. It doesn't actually *do* the saving.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyViewState : NSObject{
    static var isFromLogin = false
    static var isFromCQ = false
}
```

add above to anywhere in any view controller  it will accessible everywhere like

```
MyViewState.isFromLogin
```

Answer (score 1):

make a shared class like following this will save data all the time

```
Class ProfilClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
    static let sharedInstance = ProfilClass()
// here methods etc will go 
}
```

and

```
ProfilClass.sharedInstance.(properties or method)
```

If you want data after app relaunched too , then save this to Userdefaults and load this class again and access anywhere in the app

Answer (score 0):

```
var isFromLogin = false
var isFromCQ = false
Class ProfilClass: NSObject, NSCoding {.......}
```

add above to class it will accessible everywhere publicly . OR also create .swift file and declare constant variable to access globally